# Aggregater Stage outputting incorrect row count

Tags: etl, datastage

I have the following job that takes the row count of a sequential file. When running on multiple nodes for example 4 I am getting 4 different row counts. How would I go about outputting only one row with the row count.

Source --> transformer (this has a dummy row for counting) --> Aggregator Stage --> Sequential File

Any help would be greatly appreciated!! Thanks!

Comment: Aggregator Stage need key columns for grouping. Partition of data will be done on these key columns , if the partition type is left as auto. So the problem is not because of multiple node. From your statement, I think that you use that dummy row as key. Make sure that dummy row has the same value in all rows. Then only all rows will go to the same partition and you will get one row with total row count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set the Execution mode to Sequential for the aggregator stage (Stage-Advanced tab). If the job isnt processing large volumes of data you may not experience much of a slow-down in performance. If you DO process large volumes then it makes more sense to leave the aggregator as Parallel, then add another aggregator and set THAT to sequential instead